# __UUPSUpgradeable_init() is empty by default. UUPS, upgradeable contracts

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

`__UUPSUpgradeable_init()` is empty by default.
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol
[image]

Also I see in different contract this type of initializing:

```
`function initialize() {
     __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
}`
```

Why they need it? There is no any code. Thank you.